# Не могу передать значение переменной в Python

Tags: python, переменные, методы

Добро времени суток! Вопрос конечно ламерский, но путевой информации в гугле не нашел, либо глаза не с того места растут. В общем не могу передать значение булевой переменной в метод модуля.
Собственно есть два питоновских файла. Один используется как каркас, другой как конструктор. Для отображения частей каркаса использую условия **IF..ELSE**
В конечном счете, не могу передать значение переменной в условие. Вроде правильно описал проблему. Могу ошибаться в трактовки слов, заранее прошу прощения. В питоне новичок, учусь на примерах. Поэтому если не сложно, то пример. Саму конструкцию передачи переменной знаю, а вот именно тут затупа.

Это главный файл **Login.py**

```
from WindowTwitchFrame import WindowTwitchFrame
import sys, os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QToolTip, QPushButton, QApplication, QLabel)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QFont, QIcon, QPixmap)

class LoginTwitch(WindowTwitchFrame):
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = WindowTwitchFrame()
    window.initUI(False)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Это файл **WindowTwitchFrame.py**

```
import sys, os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QToolTip, QPushButton, QApplication, QLabel)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QFont, QIcon, QPixmap)

class WindowTwitchFrame(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI(True)

    def initUI(self, SLTC):
        version = 'v0.0.1'

        def ShowLogoTopCenter(self):
            lTwitchLogo = QLabel(self)
            pm = QPixmap('images/logo.png')

            lTwitchLogo.setPixmap(pm)
            lTwitchLogo.setStyleSheet('background-color: #6441a5;')
            lTwitchLogo.setGeometry(250, 50, 300, 110)

        if SLTC == True:
            a = ShowLogoTopCenter(self)

        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('TwitchLight - ' + version)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icons/twitch.png'))
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: #6441a5;')
        self.setFixedSize(800, 600)
        self.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Упрощенный скелет:

Login.py

```
from WindowTwitchFrame import WindowTwitchFrame


class LoginTwitch(WindowTwitchFrame):
    window = WindowTwitchFrame()
    window.initUI(False)
```

WindowTwitchFrame.py

```
class WindowTwitchFrame(object):

    def __init__(self):
        super(WindowTwitchFrame, self).__init__()
        self.initUI(True)

    def initUI(self, SLTC):
        if SLTC:
            print "SLTC == True"
        else:
            print "SLTC == False"
```

Результат:

```
>>> SLTC == True
>>> SLTC == False
```

Comment: Благодарю! Сейчас буду сидеть и читать про **kivy.app**

Comment: Ну у меня просто данного модуля нет

Comment: и что касается super() я обратил внимание.

Comment: Дабы не вводить вас в заблуждение - изменил ответ.